# Should I set a maximum length for journal content in the database?

Tags: python, django, database, postgresql

I am using Django and PostgreSQL to do a Journal Application. What I'm thinking of is not limiting the length of the journal context so that the user can write as much as they want. What will happen if I don't set a maximum length? Should I set a maximum length for journal content in the database?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is already a type for that: a [**`TextField`** <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.TextField), this will normally use the database limit, which is for practical reasons "unlimited". It will also work with a `textarea` as form widget by default.

For a [**`CharField`** <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.CharField), you are required to pass a `max_length`, if not the constructor will reject it.